# Find the last occurrence of "in" then capture the text there after

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The bold text is what I'm trying to capture "**the yard**".

One boat in here. (in **the yard**)
One boat in here. in **the yard**

My regex captures "here. (in the yard", it gets caught on the first "in", but im trying to get it to only catch on the last appearance of "in".

My current regex is

```
\s\(?in([^\)]+)\)?$
```

If you know the solution please explain the regex, I would like to understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\s` Find a space
`\(?` Zero or one (i.e., optional) open parenthesis
`in` Literal *i* followed by literal *n*
`[^\)]+` CAPTURE: One or more characters, none of which are `)` (and maybe `\` (not sure about this bit))
`\)?` Optional close parenthesis
`$` End of line

This clearly matches the first string, with `here. (in the yard` being captured.

fix:

```
.*\s\(?in([^\)]+)\)?$
```

The `.*` causes the regex engine to first find the end of the string. It then backtracks from there to the last *in*.

Comment: its above than my level but its impressive

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the Regex is for when you can use

```
$str = <<< TXT
One boat in here. (in the yard)
One boat in here. in the yard
TXT;

echo substr($str, strrpos($str, 'in') + 3); // 'the yard'
```

See

- [`strrpos` — Find the position of the last occurrence of a substring in a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php)
- [`substr` — Return part of a string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

This does not obey word boundaries though. If you need word boundaries, Regex are indeed a better choice (or make the needle "in "). For a decent tutorial about Regex, see [Perl's perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html). Most, if not all, of that applies to PHP as well.

Comment: Thanks, never thought that php would have it's own function for it. though. Wouldn't "strstr" be better as "strrchr" only searches with one charter if I understand it correctly. Still i'll leave the question open for a few more minutes as I still want to know how to match the last occurrence of 2 or more characters in a regex :)

Comment: I you don't mind about the word `in`, this code is the best. But if the word `in` is meaningful, this code may not work as expected. `strrchr('I am in the living room', 'in')` will return `'ing room`';

Comment: @Xavier true, that's why it says find the last "character" (sequence), not word :)

Comment: @Mint yes. My bad. It's different from `strstr`. Updated answer. Threw in a link to a nice regex tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

The regex is

```
/.*(?<=\bin\b)(?P<founded>.*?)$/
```

- `\b` is a word boundary
- `(?<= ....)` is a look behind.
- `$` is the end of the string
- `.*` is greedy
- `.*?` is ungreedy

So the full code is

```
<?php
$str = "I am in the backyard";
preg_match('/.*(?<=\bin\b)(?P<founded>.*?)$/', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches['founded']);

// returns string(13) " the backyard"
```

Or simply

```
$str = "I am in the light in the backyard";
$matches = preg_split('/\bin\b/', $str);
var_dump(end($matches));

// returns string(13) " the backyard"
```

Comment: What if the string is "I am in the light in the backyard"? I get " the light in the backyard"... Doesn't seem to work with 2 or more "in"s

Comment: tip: if you use [`/x (PCRE_EXTENDED)`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) you can use whitespace and documentation inside your Regex. That would make it more readable.